# Set string to a specified length in PHP

Tags: php, string

I need to have a string that has a specified length and replace the excess characters with a letter.

e.g.

My original string is : "JOHNDOESMITH". The length should be up to 25 characters only.
I need my string to become "XXXXXXXXXXXXXJOHNDOESMITH" (13 X's and 12 chars from the original string).

Anybody please tell me how to achieve this? Is there a string function for this? I've been racking my brains out for quite some time now and I still can't find a solution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: It's because of the project I'm doing. I need to send a downloadable .txt file to a bank containing the information. I'm presuming they're using Cobol so the info needs to be in some kind of format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to do it...

```
echo str_pad($str, 25, 'X', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/PtirfoYp).

You could use [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) to do it...

```
echo str_repeat('X', max(0, 25 - strlen($str))) . $str;
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/iQB0X201).

> The length should be up to 25 characters only.

You can always run `substr($str, 0, 25)` to truncate your string to the first 25 characters.

Comment: "The length should be up to 25 characters only" - these will output the input if it's longer than 25, not truncate it (though to be fair the OP didn't specify what should happen if over 25 characters)

Comment: It's okay, guys. Thanks for helping me! You all are the greatest! :D

Answer (score 4):

We can use `printf()` or `sprintf()` function.

```
 $format= "%'X25s";
 printf($format, "JOHNDOESMITH");  // Prints a formatted string
 $output = sprintf($format, "JOHNDOESMITH");  // Returns a formatted string
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the str_pad function:

```
$a="JOHNDOESMITH";   
$b=str_pad($a,25,'X',STR_PAD_LEFT);
print_r($b);
```